# XML Request from strong-soap

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, strong-soap

I am using [strong-soap](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap), and it is working well.

How do I locate the request and response XML that strong-soap has generated?

I would like to review and possibly log the XML, so that I can use the converted XML while testing the WSDL directly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but for people that may have the same problem in the future, here is how you can log your inbound and outbound requests in XML format:

```
server = soap.listen(...)
server.log = function(type, data) {
    // type is 'received' or 'replied'
    // data is the xml sent or received
};
```

References: [strong-soap Github repo](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap#server-logging)